# Reallocating memory and adding a string at the reallocated memory space in C

Tags: c, memory-management, dynamic, realloc

I am having trouble adding "records" at the end of a dynamically allocated string array. Before reallocating more memory for the records to be added, everything works fine, and then I basically replicate what I initially did but now with realloc. And after I am done inputting the added Records I get an error and I don't know how to go about adding records. NOTE* The posed code is really stripped down from the original. I've tried many things but to no avail, thanks for all the help in advance.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define STRINGSIZE 21

void addRecords( char **Names, int classSize);

int main(){
    char **Names;
    int classSize, i;

    //User will be able to choose how many records he woudld like to input.
    printf("Please indicate number of records you want to enter:\n");
    scanf("%d", &classSize);

    Names=malloc(classSize*sizeof(char*));

    for (i=0; i<classSize; i++) {
        Names[i]=malloc(STRINGSIZE*sizeof(char));
    }
    printf("Please input records of students (enter a new line after each record), with following format: first name....\n");

    for (i=0; i<classSize; i++) {
        scanf("%s", *(Names + i));
    }

    for (i=0; i<classSize; i++) {
        printf("%s ", *(Names+i));                
        printf("\n\n");
    }

addRecords(Names, classSize);
}

void addRecords(char **Names, int classSize){
    int addition, i;

    printf("How many records would you like to add?\n");
    scanf("%d", &addition);

    Names=realloc(Names, (classSize+addition)*sizeof(char*));

    for (i=classSize; i<(classSize+addition); i++) {
        Names[i]=malloc(STRINGSIZE*sizeof(char));
    }

    printf("Please input records of students (enter a new line after each record), with followingformat: first name....\n");

    for (i=classSize; i<classSize+addition; i++) {
        scanf("%s", *(Names + (classSize + i)));
    }
    printf("\n\n");
    for (i=0; i<classSize+addition; i++) {
        printf("%s ", *(Names+i));
    }

    printf("\n\n");
}
```

Comment: Please indent your code.

Comment: `I get an error` .. please show us that.

Comment: @2501 sorry, I think it's better know

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are writing out of the bounds of the array:

```
for (i=classSize; i<classSize+addition; i++) {
    scanf("%s", *(Names + (classSize + i)));
```

change to

```
for (i=classSize; i<classSize+addition; i++) {
    scanf("%s", *(Names + i));
```

Note that `Names[i]` is more readable than `*(Names + i)`

Comment: Yes, I see it now. I don't know how I missed that. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

First, your `Names` argument is passed by value to `addRecords` function, so you will be unable to observe the reallocation outside it (it may work if the reallocation does not give you a new address, but in general it does so).

Second, the loop in `addRecords` contains a mistake. You loop from `classeSize` up to `classSize+addition` and you use it in `(Names + (classSize+i))`. That should be either looping from 0 to `addition` or using it as `Names + i`.

Comment: Actually it isn't declared in main.

Comment: @2501 due to bad indentation, at first attempt, it looks so.

Comment: @Jean-BaptisteYunès sorry for the bad formatting, and thanks a lot for the help.

Comment: Don't worry, **I** made the mistake.