# Getting an error in the second call of the same print function in C

Tags: c, dynamic, scope, printf

I am trying to print the records after adding on to the original amount of records, and I am successful in doing so within the addRecords function, but outside of the function I have an error, but I am having understanding how. I'm passing the Names array through pointer and the classSize variable is global. So I don't see why it works in the addRecords function and not in the main funtion. All help is appreciated, thanks in advance.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define STRINGSIZE 21
int classSize;
void addRecords( char **Names);

int main() {
    char **Names;
    int i;

    //User will be able to choose how many records he woudld like to input.
    printf("Please indicate number of records you want to enter:\n");
    scanf("%d", &classSize);

    Names = malloc(classSize*sizeof(char*));

    for (i = 0; i < classSize; i++) {
        Names[i] = malloc(STRINGSIZE * sizeof(char));
    }

    printf("Please input records of students (enter a new line after each record), with following format: first name....\n");

    for (i = 0; i < classSize; i++) {
        scanf("%s", *(Names + i));
    }

    for (i = 0; i < classSize; i++) {
        printf("%s ", *(Names+i));
        printf("\n\n");
    }

    addRecords(Names);

    printf("SECOND PRINT\n\n");

    for (i = 0; i < classSize; i++) {
        printf("%s \n", *(Names+i));
    }
}

void addRecords(char **Names) {
    int addition, i, temp;

    temp = classSize;
    printf("How many records would you like to add?\n");
    scanf("%d", &addition);
    classSize += addition;

    Names = realloc(Names, (classSize) * sizeof(char*));

    for (i = temp; i < (classSize); i++) {
        Names[i] = malloc(STRINGSIZE * sizeof(char));
    }

    printf("Please input records of students (enter a new line after each record), with followingformat: first name....\n");

    for (i=temp; i<classSize; i++) {
        scanf("%s", *(Names +i));
    }
    printf("\n\n");
    printf("FIRST PRINT\n\n");

    for (i = 0; i < classSize; i++) {
        printf("%s \n", *(Names+i));
    }

    printf("\n\n");
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/27200719/4082723

Comment: @2501 I messed around with making Names a gobal variable and I honestly don't know how to go about passing it by reference. Any tips?

Comment: what error are you getting?

Comment: The second print call is looking at a vacant memory space, and I am trying to figure out how to make the realloc in the addRecords function global. @rpattiso

Comment: @kenshin Jean-Baptiste Yunès answer to your [other question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27200661/reallocating-memory-and-adding-a-string-at-the-reallocated-memory-space-in-c/27200719#27200719) answers this problem. You need to add `return Names` to `addRecords` and update its return type, and make the call as `Names = addRecords(Names)` in main.

Comment: use `%20s` as the scanf specifier to avoid problems associated with buffer overflows

Answer (score 1, accepted):

C uses pass-by-value. The `Names` inside `addRecords` is a different variable to `Names` inside `main`.  A copy is created when you call the function.

To fix this you either need to pass `Names` by reference, or make it a global variable, or return the updated copy via function return value.

In your actual code, attempting to use `Names` in `main()` after it had been passed to `realloc` in the function, causes undefined behaviour (realloc makes its argument indeterminate).

Comment: I understand got it now, thanks appreciate the help!